# conseguir la URL actual

Tags: javascript, plugin, chrome

Muy buenas 
he creado un `plugin` para chrome y me falla a la hora de conseguir la `URL` actual para después trabajar con ella tan solo con un botón

en **mainfest.json** tengo esto:

```
{
"name": "Dom_Test",
"version": "1",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "Test de dominio con la herramienta newp, se podrĂ¡n obtener los resultados en PDF",
"permissions": [ 
  "tabs"
],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "/imagenes/registro.png",
         "default_title": "Test de dominios",
        "default_popup":"popup.html"
    }
}
```

y en **popup.html** lo siguiente:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test de dominios</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">


      <!--  acciones de los js -->
      <script src="popup.js"></script> 



<style type="text/css"> 
body{
  min-width:360px;
}
a{
  color:#f90;
  text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover{
  text-decoration:underline;
}
p{
  font:0.8em sans-serif;
}
h1{
  font:1em sans-serif;
  color:#fff;
  background:#000;
  padding:5px
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div><h1>TEST DE DOMINIO</h1></div>
    <p>
    <form>
<button name="button"  onclick="functionaunporcrear();">Botonazo</button>
<div id="host"> </div>
    </form>
    <hr>
    Pie
</body>
</html>

y en popup.js tengo lo siguiente:

    $(documento).ready(function (){
    chrome.tabs.get.Selected(null, function (tab)
    {
        var link = documento.createElement('a');
        link.href = tab.url;
        $('#host').html("Host : "+link.hostname);
    })  
});
```

me he ayudado de varias guías y videotutoriales pero no consigo la url actual

una vez tenga la url haré una petición a una dirección con esa url pero antes necesito la URL actual

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mediante javascript puedes obtenerla de la siguiente manera:

```
var urlActual=window.location.href;
```

Un ejemplo del funcionamiento con OnClick:

```js
function mifunction(){
  var urlActual=window.location.href;
  console.log("La url es:" + urlActual);
}
```

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <button name="button" onclick="mifunction();">Botonazo</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Un ejemplo del funcionamiento con manejador de eventos:

```js
document.getElementById("botonazo").addEventListener("click", function(){
  var urlActual=window.location.href;
  console.log("La url es:" + urlActual);
});
```

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <button name="button" id="botonazo">Botonazo</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Ejemplo con manejador y onload:

```js
window.onload=function(){ 
  document.getElementById("botonazo").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var urlActual=window.location.href;
    console.log("La url es:" + urlActual);
  });
}
```

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <button name="button" id="botonazo">Botonazo</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias, es posible que sea correcto pero me da fallo a la hora de intentar probarlo llamando a la función:
<button name="button"  onclick="mifunction();">Botonazo</button>

podrías ayudarme??
gracias

Comment: ¿qué error te está dando?

Comment: Acabo de añadir un snippet a mi respuesta con un ejemplo, aunque ahí en vez de coger la url de esta pregunta, coge la del snippet,

Comment: gracias por la respuesta
se me muestra el botonazo pero luego no hace nada y el error que me da es al cargar el plugin en el navegador aparece error, si entro obtengo esto:

Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
Contexto

creí que con "permissions": [ 
  "tabs"
],
en manifest.json sería suficiente

Comment: vale, eso creo que me pasó a mi hace poco en Microsoft Sharepoint, que por política de seguridad no permite realizar acciones "onclick", por tanto tienes que realizar la acción desde un manejador de eventos. Acabo de añadir otro ejemplo con manejador de eventos a la respuesta. A ver si hay suerte y es ese el problema :)

Comment: ufff que buena, creo que estamos mas cerca muchas gracias pero sigue sin funcionarme, ahora el eror es este: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: jajaja vale, eso te pasa porque cuando estás añadiendo el manejador, el DOM de la página no está cargado y por tanto al hacer el getElementById("botonazo") no lo encuentra, por eso lo del Null. Pon el javascript al final de todo o añádelo dentro de un window.onload para que así el script se ejecute una vez terminado de cargar el DOM. Añado un ejemplo a la respuesta. Ya con eso esperemos que funcione :)

Comment: Nada, que sigue sin mostrarme la URL....
he probado haciendo la llamada al js justo antes del </body>
y me hacía lo mismo y poniendolo en el window.onmload tampoco:
window.onload = function(){
 document.getElementById("botonazo").addEventListener("click", function(){
  var urlActual=window.location.href;
  console.log("La url es:" + urlActual);
});
};
esta super cerca pero no se que es lo que falla, el error sigue saliendo el mismo

Comment: pues no se me ocurre qué puede estar fallando. entiendo que al botón le has puesto el ID.